# Deny to access to id of user in Foreignkey model

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-models, django-views

```
        --WHY I CANT TO ACCESS TO ID OF USER AND PRODUCT WITH user__id and product__id?
        i have error: (The view store.views.submit_review didn't return an HttpResponse object. It returned None instead).
        <pre><code>
    i define some code for rating post for any user user
        --#views
        def submit_review(request, product_id):
            url = request.META.get('HTTP_REFERER')
            if request.method == 'POST':
                try:
                    reviews = ReviewRating.objects.get(user__id=request.user.id,Product__id=product_id) #my problem is here
                    form = Reviewform(request.POST, instance=reviews)
                    form.save()
                    messages.success(request, 'Thank you!your review has been updated.')
                    return redirect(url)
                except ReviewRating.DoesNotExist:
                    form = Reviewform(request.POST)
                    if form.is_valid():
                        data = ReviewRating()
                        data.subject = form.cleaned_data['subject']
                        data.review = form.cleaned_data['review']
                        data.rating = form.cleaned_data['rating']
                        data.ip = request.META.get['REMOTE_ADDR']
                        data.product_id = product_id
                        data.user_id = request.user.id
                        data.save()
                        messages.success(request, 'Thank you! Your review has been submitted')
                        return redirect(url)
        </code></pre>
```

this section i define model.I checked this part it work correctly

```
define model for views in my app
#models
class ReviewRating(models.Model):
Product = models.ForeignKey(product, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
user = models.ForeignKey(Account, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
subject = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True)
review = models.TextField(max_length=500, blank=True)
rating = models.FloatField()
ip = models.CharField(max_length=20, blank=True)
status = models.BooleanField(default=True)
created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
```

```
            def __str__(self):
                return self.subject
```

this part i define url
#urls
define path for html and views
urlpatterns = [
path('submit_review/int:product_id/',views.submit_review,name='submit_review')
]

Comment: can you provide the Account model, please??

Answer (score 0):

your model is not clear. It would be better if you could atleast share your full model.py file
if you provide the objective of your service with **models.py**, **serializers.py**, **views.py** I think I will be able to help more specifically

till now, one issue i've found in the the url section is that you need to add **< >** on int:product_id.
it should be,

```
urlpatterns = [
path('submit_review/<int:product_id>/',views.submit_review,name='submit_review')
]
```

Comment: yes its correct : path('submit_review/<int:product_id>/',views.submit_review,name='submit_review')

Comment: when i write my post its changed

Comment: my question that is why i cant get object in foreignkey model with this( __id)

Comment: using foreign key means, you are inheriting another model in that particular field. First, you need to create that model. Then you can use a foreign key to inherit the characteristics of that model into another one. 

That means you need to create a model named 'Product' with the field 'id'. then you can fetch the product id from there.
I hope I've cleared your confusion.